# newOutputStream Close file

Tags: xml, groovy, jgit

I write to file some text after check by XmlParser.
All work fine, but code, don't close that file, then i have problem latter in program with it. It create .tmp file. How close my file after that action ?

```
def path = new File("my/path"))
def xml = new XmlParser().parse(path)
        xml.appendNode("include", [
                myAppendToCheck"
        ])
        XmlUtil.serialize(xml, path.newOutputStream())            

    path.newOutputStream().flush()
    path.newOutputStream().close()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is that you create 3 different output streams. Just store the stream in a variable:

```
def stream = path.newOutputStream()
XmlUtil.serialize(xml, stream)
stream.close()
```

Note also that flush is not necessary before the stream is closed.

Comment: That's very helpful, i'm still newbie in java. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Just use `withOutputStream`

```
def path = new File("my/path"))
def xml = new XmlParser().parse(path)

xml.appendNode("include", [
    myAppendToCheck"
])

path.withOutputStream { os ->
    XmlUtil.serialize(xml, os)            
}
```

That will close the stream for you when the closure finishes...

> i'm still newbie in java

And this is Groovy, not Java ;-)